# How can I see all test data in CiviCRM?

Tags: civimember, testing

I'm doing tests on a test server, but when I make changes using test data, the test data is hidden. I know this is by design, but it makes it impossible to actually check if things are working.

I have a membership that was entered as a test, so it doesn't show up for the user.

Now, that would be fine if it was a live server. But I'm running a test server, so I would like to be able to just turn test data on across the whole install.

OR, ideally, be able to turn test data on for my user.

So no one else sees the test data...

Either solution is fine.

IS there a way of doing something like this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify why, given this is a Test server, you don't just use non-test data?

Comment: I'm testing credit card transactions, so would like to be sure that only the test transactions are taking place. Maybe there's another way of doing that?

I'm also running in debug/testing mode so that emails don't go out etc etc.

It does seem though that having a full test mode would be useful for those times when you are on a live server, and just want to run some tests for something you have done on the test server, and are making live.

I'm still learning CiviCRM, so perhaps there's some better ways to do this?

Comment: not sure what I can add at this point. as far as i am concerned, the only 'good' testing with credit cards is one that takes $1 off a real credit card ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of a way to turn on test data as you put it but here are some work arounds.

To find test the records, in searches (advanced search, membership search etc) there is a field "Membership is a Test" by default this is set to No but if you want to find test record such as the one specified above you can switched this to Yes.

Another option, if the reason you are using test mode is to test a payment processor without spending money and this site is just for testing then I would put in your test processor details into the live payments section for you payment processor. Then you can run "Live" actions but not spend money. You can always change these details back afterward.

Comment: Ah right. Putting the test API keys in the LIve section of the payment processor should work. Duh! I should have thought of that.

THe problem I'm having with seeing the test information is that there is indeed a Test Membership, and it will find that person with that test. But then clicking on the membership tab of that person does not show the test data. This seems.... suboptimal.